# Certbot installation from backports on Debian Jessie

Tags: debian, apt, backports

While trying to install Certbot on Debian Jessie I needed backports according to [certbot installation instruction](https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/debianjessie-nginx).
It failed. Then I tried to [add backborts to Debian *sources.list* file](https://backports.debian.org/Instructions/). It failed too. So how to install  Certbot on Jessie? I would also like to know how to add backports.

Here you are my tries:

```
root@deployer:~# apt-get install certbot
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package certbot
root@deployer:~# apt-get install certbot
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package certbot
root@deployer:~# 
root@deployer:~# cat /etc/*-release|grep VER
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
root@deployer:~# echo deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-backports/ jessie-backports main > /etc/apt/sources.list
root@deployer:~# cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-backports/ jessie-backports main
root@deployer:~# apt-get update
Ign http://ftp.debian.org jessie-backports InRelease
Ign http://ftp.debian.org jessie-backports Release.gpg
Ign http://ftp.debian.org jessie-backports Release
Err http://ftp.debian.org jessie-backports/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 130.89.148.12 80]
Ign http://ftp.debian.org jessie-backports/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ftp.debian.org jessie-backports/main Translation-en
W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-backports/dists/jessie-backports/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 130.89.148.12 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
root@deployer:~# apt-get install certbot
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package certbot
root@deployer:~#
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add backports to your sources.list you have to edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file adding this line:

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main
```

Once you edit your source.list file, you have to run apt-get update before installing your package.So run:

```
apt-get update
```

And now you can install your package:

```
apt-get -t jessie-backports install "package"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main
```

and **NOT**

```
http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-backports/ jessie-backports main
```

Use copy+paste next time!